# java spring rabbit freezes

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a spring rabbit application, and when I send 1k requests per second, my app stops consuming and just gets freezed. My app just takes a value from an external service. I have 5 concurrent consumers in the config and topic exchange. How to debug it and possible fixes?

```
@Autowired
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory f = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    f.setHost(env.getRequiredProperty("rabbit.host"));
    //f.setPublisherReturns(true);
    f.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("rabbit.pass"));
    f.setPort(Integer.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("rabbit.port")));
    f.setPublisherConfirms(true);
    f.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("rabbit.login"));
    f.setVirtualHost(env.getRequiredProperty("rabbit.virtual.host"));
    return f;
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate t = new RabbitTemplate();
    t.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    t.setRoutingKey("default_queue.*");
    t.setExchange(EXCHANGE_NAME);
   // t.setMessageConverter(new JsonMessageConverter());
    t.setReplyTimeout(30000);
    return t;
}

@Bean
public RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin() {
    return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
}

@Bean
public TopicExchange exchange() {
    return new TopicExchange(EXCHANGE_NAME);
}


@Bean(name = OrderValidatorData.QUEUE_BEAN_NAME)
Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(OrderValidatorData.QUEUE_BEAN_NAME);
}

/**
 * Bind queue and exchange by it`s routing keys pattern
 * @param q queue
 * @param e exchange
 * @return resgiter bean in spring context
 */
@Bean(name = OrderValidatorData.QUEUE_BINDING_NAME)
Binding binding(@Qualifier(OrderValidatorData.QUEUE_BEAN_NAME) Queue q, TopicExchange e) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(q).to(e).with(OrderValidatorData.WORKER_NAME);
}

/**
 * Rabbit container. Every listener and every worker will have it`s own container
 * do avoif complexicity and multithreading issues
 * @param connectionFactory autowired connection factory
 * @param listenerAdapter autowired listener adapter
 * @return register bean in spring context
 */
@Bean(name = OrderValidatorData.RABBIT_CONTAINER_NAME)
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                         @Qualifier(OrderValidatorData.LISTENER_ADAPTER_NAME)
                                         MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
    return WorkerConfigHelper.rabbitConfigListenerContainer(
            connectionFactory,
            listenerAdapter,
            OrderValidatorData.QUEUE_BEAN_NAME,
            WorkerConfigHelper.GLOBAL_CONCURRENT_CONSUMERS);
}

/**
 * Listener adapter class - linking listener and container
 * @return registers in spring context
 */
@Bean(name = OrderValidatorData.LISTENER_ADAPTER_NAME)
MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter() {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(orderValidatorListener);
}
```

Comment: Do you have sufficient memory to accept so many requests?

Comment: Most likely the container threads are stuck in user code somewhere. Make sure your listener and any dependent beans are thread safe and have no possibilities of deadlocks. If there's no information that helps in the log, the first step is to take a thread dump (jstack or jvisualvm) to see what the listener threads are doing.